# How to compute prediction bands for non-linear regression?

Tags: nonlinear-regression, prediction-interval

The [help page](http://www.graphpad.com/faq/viewfaq.cfm?faq=1099) for Prism gives the following explanation for how it computes the prediction bands for non-linear regression.  Please excuse the long quote, but I am not following the second paragraph (that explains how $G|x$ is defined and $dY/dP$ is computed).  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

> The calculation of the confidence and prediction bands are fairly
>   standard. Read on for the details of how Prism computes prediction and
>   confidence bands of nonlinear regression.
>
> First, let's define G|x, which is the gradient of the parameters at a
>   particular value of X and using all the best-fit values of the
>   parameters. The result is a vector, with one element per parameter.
>   For each parameter, it is defined as dY/dP, where Y is the Y value of
>   the curve given the particular value of X and all the best-fit
>   parameter values, and P is one of the parameters.)
>
> G'|x is that gradient vector transposed, so it is a column rather than
>   a row of values.
>
> Cov is the covariance matrix (inversed Hessian from last iteration).
>   It is a square matrix with the number of rows and columns equal to the
>   number of parameters. Each item in the matrix is the covariance
>   between two parameters.
>
> Now compute c = G'|x * Cov * G|x. The result is a single number for
>   any value of X.
>
> The confidence and prediction bands are centered on the best fit
>   curve, and extend above and below the curve an equal amount.
>
> The confidence bands extend above and below the curve by:    =
>   sqrt(c)*sqrt(SS/DF)*CriticalT(Confidence%, DF)
>
> The prediction bands extend a further distance above and below the
>   curve, equal to:    = sqrt(c+1)*sqrt(SS/DF)*CriticalT(Confidence%,
>   DF)

Comment: Hope this helps: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/74334/question-about-prediction-bands-for-non-linear-regression-computation?lq=1

Comment: Hope this helps: 

http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/74334/question-about-prediction-bands-for-non-linear-regression-computation?lq=1

Comment: This is indeed known as the delta method and uses a first order Taylor approximation. It is better though to use a 2nd order Taylor approximation for this - the predictNLS function in the propagate package does that if you're interested!

Answer (score 26):

This is called the Delta Method.

Suppose that you have some function $y = G(\beta,x) + \epsilon$; note that $G(\cdot)$ is a function of the parameters that you estimate, $\beta$, and the values of your predictors, $x$. First, find the derivative of this function with respect to your vector of parameters, $\beta$: $G^\prime(\beta, x)$. This says, if you change a parameter by a little bit, how much does your function change? Note that this derivative may be a function of your parameters themselves as well as the predictors. For example, if $G(\beta,x) = \exp (\beta x)$, then the derivative is $x \exp (\beta x)$, which depends upon the value of $\beta$ and the value of $x$. To evaluate this, you plug in the estimate of $\beta$ that your procedure gives, $\hat{\beta}$, and the value of the predictor $x$ where you want the prediction.

The Delta Method, derived from maximum likelihood procedures, states that the variance of $G\left(\hat{\beta}, x\right)$ is going to be 
$$G^\prime\left(\hat{\beta},x\right)^T \text{Var}\left(\hat{\beta}\right) G^\prime\left(\hat{\beta},x\right),$$
where $\text{Var}\left(\hat{\beta}\right)$ is the variance-covariance matrix of your estimates (this is equal to the inverse of the Hessian---the second derivatives of the likelihood function at your estimates). The function that your statistics packages employs calculates this value for each different value of the predictor $x$. This is just a number, not a vector, for each value of $x$.

This gives the variance of the value of the function at each point and this is used just like any other variance in calculating confidence intervals: take the square root of this value, multiply by the critical value for the normal or applicable *t* distribution relevant for a particular confidence level, and add and subtract this value to the estimate of $G(\cdot)$ at the point.

For prediction intervals, we need to take the variance of the outcome given the predictors $x$, $\text{Var}(y \mid x) \equiv \sigma^2$, into account. Hence, we must boost our variance from the Delta Method by our estimate of the variance of $\epsilon$, $\hat{\sigma}^2$, to get the variance of $y$, rather than the variance of the expected value of $y$ that is used for confidence intervals. Note that $\hat{\sigma}^2$ is the sum of squared errors (`SS` in help file notation) divided by the degrees of freedom (`DF`).

In the notation used in the help file above, it looks like their value of `c` does not take $\sigma^2$ into account; that is, the inverse of their Hessian is $\sigma^{-2}$ times the one that I give. I'm not sure why they do that. It could be a way of writing the confidence and prediction intervals in a more familiar way (of $\sigma$ times some number times some critical value). The variance that I give is actually `c*SS/DF` in their notation.

For example, in the familiar case of linear regression, their `c` would be $\left(x^\prime x\right)^{-1}$, while the $\text{Var}\left(\hat{\beta}\right) = \sigma^2 \left(x^\prime x\right)^{-1}$.

Comment: Can you explain the ci calculation? Doesn't look like critical point of t * sqrt(var)

Comment: I think that I understand their calculation; I updated my response.

Comment: Charlie, thanks very much for a detailed response.  I intend to write code to be able to compute the 95% prediction band.  I will let you know how that goes.

Comment: @Charlie - very very nice!

Comment: @Charlie. Thanks. I've added a sentence to our GraphPad Prism FAQ explaining that we use cov to mean the normalized covariance matrix (each value ranges from -1 to 1). I've also added a link to this page, which is great for anyone seeking mathematical details.

Comment: How does `SS` figure in logistic regression, or other regressions which don't minimise the sum of squares? Which value should be used?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to some Jupyter Notebooks and Python scripts I wrote that show how to calculate confidence intervals and prediction intervals for nonlinear regressions using the delta method:

https://github.com/gjpelletier/delta_method

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/359911)