# Question about prediction bands for non-linear regression computation?

Tags: nonlinear-regression, prediction-interval

I am interested in computing prediction bands for a non-linear regression (log-logistic function with 3 parameters). I have read the Prism help page:

> The calculation of the confidence and prediction bands are fairly standard. Read on for the details of how Prism computes prediction and confidence bands of nonlinear regression.
>
> First, let's define G|x, which is the gradient of the parameters at a particular value of X and using all the best-fit values of the parameters. The result is a vector, with one element per parameter. For each parameter, it is defined as dY/dP, where Y is the Y value of the curve given the particular value of X and all the best-fit parameter values, and P is one of the parameters.)
>
> G'|x is that gradient vector transposed, so it is a column rather than a row of values.
>
> Cov is the covariance matrix (inversed Hessian from last iteration). It is a square matrix with the number of rows and columns equal to the number of parameters. Each item in the matrix is the covariance between two parameters.
>
> Now compute c = G'|x * Cov * G|x. The result is a single number for any value of X.
>
> The confidence and prediction bands are centered on the best fit curve, and extend above and below the curve an equal amount.
>
> The confidence bands extend above and below the curve by: = sqrt(c)*sqrt(SS/DF)*CriticalT(Confidence%, DF)
>
> The prediction bands extend a further distance above and below the curve, equal to: = sqrt(c+1)*sqrt(SS/DF)*CriticalT(Confidence%, DF)

I also read the topic [How to compute prediction bands for non-linear regression?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/15423/how-to-compute-prediction-bands-for-non-linear-regression?answertab=active#tab-top).

But I still do not understand something : how to compute the Hessian matrix. I do not think it is (I do not get values between -1 and 1), but, is it the second-order partial derivatives of my log-logistic function ?

In Prism, it refers to the "Hessian from last iteration" while in the topic, it is written "the second derivatives of the likelihood function at your estimates".

The likelihood function I use is ( -*N* / 2 ) * log( sum( ( *dat* - *model* ) .^2 ) ) where *N* is the number of observations, *dat* is a vector with data being fitted and *model* is a vector of model values. I do not really understand how it would be possible to do a second order derivatives of this function.

Could anyone give me a hand with this ?

Comment: Why would the second order partial derivatives be between -1 and 1?

Comment: Hello Glen, In Prism, they use Cov to refer to the normalized covariance matrix, where each value is between -1 and 1. I do not really understand why it is (might be) important

Comment: I made a mistake when writing the GraphPad Prism 6 help. While Prism only reports (optionally) the normalized covariance matrix, the calculations of the confidence and prediction bands define "cov"to be the nonnormalized covariance matrix. This FAQ is now correct:
http://graphpad.com/support/faq/how-does-prism-compute-confidence-and-prediction-bands-for-nonlinear-regression/

Comment: This is indeed known as the delta method and uses a first order Taylor approximation. It is better though to use a 2nd order Taylor approximation for this - the predictNLS function in the propagate package does that if you're interested!